# How can I find eigen values and eigen vectors of a symbolic matrix?

Tags: eigenvalues

How can I find eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this system given as a matrix?

```
 {{x + Cosh[2 t], -I, (x + Sinh[2 t])/Sqrt[2], 0, (x + Sinh[2 t])/Sqrt[2], 0, 0, 0}, 
  {I, x + Cosh[2 t], 0, (x + Sinh[2 t])/Sqrt[2], 0, -((x + Sinh[2 t])/Sqrt[2]), 0, 0}, 
  {(x + Sinh[2 t])/Sqrt[2], 0, 1/2 (1 + x + Cosh[2 t]), -I, 1/2 (1 + x + Cosh[2 t]), 0, 0, 0}, 
  {0, (x + Sinh[2 t])/Sqrt[2], I, 1/2 (1 + x + Cosh[2 t]), 0, 1/2 (-1 - x - Cosh[2 t]), 0, 0}, 
  {(x + Sinh[2 t])/Sqrt[2], 0, 1/2 (1 + x + Cosh[2 t]), 0, 1/2 (1 + x + Cosh[2 t]), -I, 0, 0}, 
  {0, -((x + Sinh[2 t])/Sqrt[2]), 0, 1/2 (-1 - x - Cosh[2 t]), I, 1/2 (1 + x + Cosh[2 t]), 0, 0}, 
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, I}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -I, 1}}
```

Comment: Have you tried `Eigensystem`?

Comment: yes but a very large output is taken out

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher sir can you help me regarding this that what can I do for that system I want the answer in the compact form

Comment: Yeah, that's what is about to happen with symbolic computations. Note that finding the eigenvalues amounts to finding the roots of the charakteristic polynomial.  Since your matrix has size $8 \times 8$, this polynomial is of degree $8$, hence a closed form expression for all its roots need not exist. That's why certain `Root` expressions show up.

Comment: Probably, nobody can help you here: Your problem is not that the result wasn't correct; your problem is that you don't _like_ the result.

Comment: Btw. You will get concise numerical approximations to the eigensystem when you substitute concrete floating point values for `x` and `t`.

Comment: yes I want what can in do that numerically

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking only for numerical solution, just defer the evaluation of `Eigensystem` until numerical data is present. You can use this function for that:

```
eigsys[x_, t_] := Eigensystem[N[
    {{x + Cosh[2 t], -I, (x + Sinh[2 t])/Sqrt[2], 
      0, (x + Sinh[2 t])/Sqrt[2], 0, 0, 0}, {I, x + Cosh[2 t], 
      0, (x + Sinh[2 t])/Sqrt[2], 0, -((x + Sinh[2 t])/Sqrt[2]), 0, 
      0}, {(x + Sinh[2 t])/Sqrt[2], 0, 1/2 (1 + x + Cosh[2 t]), -I, 
      1/2 (1 + x + Cosh[2 t]), 0, 0, 0}, {0, (x + Sinh[2 t])/Sqrt[2], 
      I, 1/2 (1 + x + Cosh[2 t]), 0, 1/2 (-1 - x - Cosh[2 t]), 0, 
      0}, {(x + Sinh[2 t])/Sqrt[2], 0, 1/2 (1 + x + Cosh[2 t]), 0, 
      1/2 (1 + x + Cosh[2 t]), -I, 0, 
      0}, {0, -((x + Sinh[2 t])/Sqrt[2]), 0, 1/2 (-1 - x - Cosh[2 t]),
       I, 1/2 (1 + x + Cosh[2 t]), 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
      I}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -I, 1}}
    ]];
```

Comment: sir this is not working in Mathematica

Comment: What do you mean, it doesn't work? Which version of Mathematica do you use?